# Free Fat Framework a Select with ILIKE Postgresql Statement

Tags: php, postgresql, fat-free-framework

i have a problem with the F3 Framework.

I'm trying to search for some text, which was typed by the user.

Here some statement:

```
$db->exec(array("Select userid,username,section from user 
          WHERE section=:sectionId 
          AND username ILIKE '%?%'"),
          array(':sectionId' => $sectionId),
          array( 1=> $queryString),
          NULL));
```

If there is some typo sorry, but i'm not allowed to post code from a productive system.

This statement return an empty array.

I have replaced the variables with Strings and tested it with psql, but it returns one match.

Someone an idea?

Edit:

Answer From Sn0opy:

```
$db->exec(array("Select userid,username,section from user 
            WHERE section=:sectionId 
            AND username ILIKE '%?%'"),
            array(':sectionId' => $sectionId, 1 => $queryString));
```

The Problem is, in Postgresql it is $1,$2,$3 and not '?' .

My Solution (thanks again to Sn0opy for his reply) :

You have to concat the  the String

```
('%'|| :queryString || '%')
```

This works now :

```
$db->exec(array("Select userid,username,section from user 
            WHERE section=:sectionId 
            AND username ILIKE ('%'|| :queryString || '%') ),
            array(':sectionId' => $sectionId, ':queryString' => $queryString));
```

If you don't concat the String, you will get this error :

```
ERROR:  could not determine data type of parameter $1
```

Comment: You've written `ILIKE`. I think it's also called `LIKE` in PSQL.

Comment: @Sn0opy - `ILIKE` is the case-insensitive version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got this code right from [the docs](https://github.com/bcosca/fatfree#parameterized-queries). If you recheck the docs, you will see the first array has three elements. So does the second. In your case, you have one element in the first and 3 in the last. Only the first parameter `array(':sectionId' => $sectionId)` will be applied.

This one should work:

```
      $db->exec(array("Select userid,username,section from user 
                WHERE section=:sectionId 
                AND username ILIKE '%?%'"),
                array(':sectionId' => $sectionId, 1 => $queryString));
```

Comment: Thx for your reply , there was a smallbug in this source, but it only depends on Postgresql, i have edited it in my Mainpost.